# Custom views on the list of document Libraries in a site?

Tags: document-library, view, properties

for managing contracts (collections of documents) I'm using a Document Library per contract. I will end up with hundreds (500+) of document libraries.

Is it possible to make custom views on the list of Document Libraries in a site? As far as I can see, they are listed as "boxes" (in the Site Contents page).

Can I let the user filter the document libraries by name or other properties?

Can I attach custom properties to a Document Library itself? (eg. the external ID of the contract, the customer name) Or are they to be attached to the content as columns?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create custom view (custom filter and sorting).
These links are usefull and show how to do it:

[What are SharePoint views? Learn how to use and create them](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/what-is-a-sharepoint-view-and-how-to-use-it)
[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)

Yes, the user can interact with the column (by clicking on the column header) and filter and sort the view.

And yes you can create custom columns to a document library, take a look at these:
[Create a Column in a SharePoint 2013 List or Library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrmX5cPTRkI)
[Sharepoint 2013 : Add a Column to a List or Document Library](http://guides.programming4.us/technology/sharepoint-2013---add-a-column-to-a-list-or-document-library.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think I posted the original question in a confusing way, anyway I found the answer [at this link](http://josharepoint.com/2014/11/24/change-site-contents-style-in-sharepoint-2013/): Create a custom CSS "sitecontents.css" and deploy it with a feature.

I haven't try yet.